# Suricata dont drop packets

Tags: ids, suricata, ips

I have a server with Suricata (169.69.1.11) installed and a specific rule:

```
drop ICMP any any -> 169.69.1.11 any (msg: "ping dropped";sid:10001;)
```

In other VM I execute:

```
ping 169.69.1.11 -c 5
```

so at this point, everything is bad because the pings reach, and nothing is registered on fast.log so I execute on the Suricata machine

```
sudo suricata -i enp0s8
```

and I ping another time with the same command ( 5 pings )
In my other machine every seems okay, the 5 pings seems they reach, but I look at the logs on Suricata /var/log/suricata/fast.log it drops that line

```
03/25/2022-11:11:05.231735  [wDrop] [**] [1:10001:0] ping dropped [**] [Classification: (null)] [Priority: 3] {ICMP} 169.69.1.10:8 -> 169.69.1.11:0
```

Why the pings are hitting and don't get blocked?
Why do I ping 5 times but only 1 time is logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first problem is I didn't have Suricata IPS, first delete ur iptables rules with

```
sudo iptables -F

sudo iptables -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE 
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -j NFQUEUE
```

and execute the Suricata with -D to let as bg

```
sudo Suricata -q 0 -D
```